# How to find find anagrams among words, which are given in a file

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting

How to find find anagrams among words, which are given in a file.

My solution:

Sort them and then find duplicates.

O(n mlgm). 
n: number of words, m : max size of the word

Any better solutions ?

thanks

Comment: What is `n` here?  I think you need two variables in your complexity expression; one for number of words, one for number of characters per word.

Comment: Do you mean sorting the characters of each word and compare the resulting strings?

Comment: Quantuum Bogosort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort, but besides that I guess you got a good solution there.

Answer (score 9):

**This is a solution without sorting:**
I came up with a new solution I guess. It uses the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. So the idea is to use an array of the first 26 prime numbers. Then for each letter in the input word we get the corresponding prime number A = 2, B = 3, C = 5, D = 7 … and then we calculate the product of our input word. Next we do this for each word in the dictionary and if a word matches our input word, then we add it to the resulting list. All anagrams will have the same signature because

> Any integer greater than 1 is either a prime number, or can be written
>   as a unique product of prime numbers (ignoring the order).

Here's the code. I convert the word to UPPERCASE and 65 is the position of A which corresponds to my first prime number:

```
private int[] PRIMES = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31,
        37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103,
        107, 109, 113 };
```

This is the function:

```
 private long calculateProduct(char[] letters) {
    long result = 1L;
    for (char c : letters) {
        if (c < 65) {
            return -1;
        }
        int pos = c - 65;
        result *= PRIMES[pos];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Complete description is available here:
[Anagram on dev.vvirlan.com](http://dev.vvirlan.com/new-algorithm-anagram/)

Comment: Awesome ... For sure it is unique and innovative :)

Comment: In fact the method described by you can act as a hashing function for words. Create unique hashes as dictionary key and words as values

Comment: No, hashing won't work, because you don't need unique key for each word. You need to have the same key (or hash) for all anagrams. stop, pots and tops must all have the same hash... how to achieve that? My solution provides the answer.

Comment: You didn't get my point - my answer is an enhancement and NOT alternative to your solution. Your method is the algorithm (like a hashing-function) which can be used to create a unique identifier for every word - stop/pots/tops will give same identifier. Now if the data set has 100 items and I want to check for the 50th item whether it is an anagram then I will need to preserve the previous 49 identifiers and only then I can compare. So save the identifiers in another hash-table as keys and words as list of values for each key so that comparison is O(1).

Comment: I see, you want to say that we need to enhance the search method by using some caching method? But you cannot cache all the dictionary. I mean it's too big.

Answer (score 6):

Hash all of the words using a hash function that is invariant under permutations of a word, e.g. compute the frequency count of each letter and hash that array.  Put these in a hash table and look for entries that hash to the same value (of course, you still have to test if those collisions are actual anagrams, due to the nature of hash tables).

That should run in O(n) time, assuming you choose a good hash function and your input set does not contain too many anagrams (in the worst case, if every word is an anagram of every other word, this runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time).

Answer (score 0):

```
# list of words
words = ["ROOPA","TABU","OOPAR","BUTA","BUAT" , "PAROO","Soudipta",
        "Kheyali Park", "Tollygaunge", "AROOP","Love","AOORP",
         "Protijayi","Paikpara","dipSouta","Shyambazaar",
        "jayiProti", "North Calcutta", "Sovabazaar"]

#Method 1
A = [''.join(sorted(word)) for word in words]

dict ={}

for indexofsamewords,samewords in enumerate(A):
    dict.setdefault(samewords, []).append(indexofsamewords)
    
print(dict)
#{'AOOPR': [0, 2, 5, 9, 11], 'ABTU': [1, 3, 4], 'Sadioptu': [6, 14], ' KPaaehiklry': [7], 'Taeggllnouy': [8], 'Leov': [10], 'Paiijorty': [12, 16], 'Paaaikpr': [13], 'Saaaabhmryz': [15], ' CNaachlortttu': [17], 'Saaaaborvz': [18]}

for index in dict.values(): 
    print( [words[i] for i in index ] )
```

The Output :

```
['ROOPA', 'OOPAR', 'PAROO', 'AROOP', 'AOORP']
['TABU', 'BUTA', 'BUAT']
['Soudipta', 'dipSouta']
['Kheyali Park']
['Tollygaunge']
['Love']
['Protijayi', 'jayiProti']
['Paikpara']
['Shyambazaar']
['North Calcutta']
['Sovabazaar']
```

Answer (score -1):

Better solution: assume that words have some small average length. Ask your local linguist for a reference if necessary. Then apply the algorithm you had in mind; if it's the one I have in mind, it will mathemagically have expected linear time performance, *in the number of words*.

Answer (score -1):

It's an old topic, but I'll post it in case someone stumbles upon this:

I've made a description of the process done in google spreadsheets (can be done in excel too). It's a very simple method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS1Zr.jpg

Basically you take you list of string and disassemble each string into letters. You take each "letters package" and sort them alphabetically. Assemble back into words but letters are alphabetically sorted. Sort on that assembled "words" - all anagrams land next to each other. Make a simple formula to mark anagrams.