# Checking if a word is contained within an array

Tags: c++

I want to check for a word contained within a bigger string, but not necessarily in the same order. Example: The program will check if the word "car" exists in "crqijfnsa". In this case, it does, because the second string contains c, a, and r.

Comment: In worst case, you could call std::find multiple times or just loop yourself. Not sure if there is an algorithm ready for this.

Comment: A naive **O(n+m)** way of doing it (where n is the total length of the two strings and m is the number of unique characters in the string to search for), as @AdrianKrupa suggests, is to convert both strings into a map of character counts, then check to see if the searched for string's character counts can exist in the jumbled string's character counts.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a map containing the letters "car" with the values set to 0. Cycle through the array with all the letters and if it is a letter in the word "car" change the value to 1. If all the keys in the map have a value greater than 0, than the word can be constructed. Try implementing this.

Comment: Assuming the OP needs to make the general case and not just ``car``, and could have duplicate letters in the search string, it would be better to make the search map a count of the search string's characters and then decrement them as you go through the jumble-string. If all are less than zero, you've got a match.

Answer (score 1):

An anagram is a type of word play, the result of rearranging the letters of a word or phrase to produce a new word or phrase, using all the original letters exactly once;

So, actually what you are looking for is an algorithm to check if two words are "Anagrams" are not.

Following thread provides psuedocode that might be helpful
[Finding anagrams for a given word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477339/finding-anagrams-for-a-given-word)

Answer (score 0):

A very primitive code would be something like this:

```
for ( std::string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
    for ( std::string::iterator it2=str2.begin(); it2!=str2.end(); ++it2) {
        if (*it == *it2) {
            str2.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }

if (str2.empty())
    found = true;
```

Comment: This code has issues with multiple occurences of the same character though like "ccar", but it could be a good basis, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could build up a table of count of characters of each letter in the `word` you are searching for, then decrement those counts as you work through the search `str`ing.

```
bool IsWordInString(const char* word, const char* str)
{
    // build up table of characters in word to match
    std::array<int, 256> cword = {0};
    for(;*word;++word) {
        cword[*word]++;
    }
    // work through str matching characters in word
    for(;*str; ++str) {
        if (cword[*str] > 0) {
            cword[*str]--;
        }
    }
    return std::accumulate(cword.begin(), cword.end(), 0) == 0;
}
```

It's also possible to return as soon as you find a match, but the code isn't as simple.

```
bool IsWordInString(const char* word, const char* str)
{
    // empty string
    if (*word == 0)
        return true;
    // build up table of characters in word to match
    int unmatched = 0;
    char cword[256] = {0};
    for(;*word;++word) {
        cword[*word]++;
        unmatched++;
    }
    // work through str matching characters in word
    for(;*str; ++str) {
        if (cword[*str] > 0) {
            cword[*str]--;
            unmatched--;
            if (unmatched == 0)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some test cases

```
"" in "crqijfnsa" => 1
"car" in "crqijfnsa" => 1
"ccar" in "crqijfnsa" => 0
"ccar" in "crqijfnsac" => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest (and probably fastest, test that youself :) ) implementation would be done with `std::includes`:

```
std::string testword {"car"};
std::string testarray {"crqijfnsa"};

std::sort(testword.begin(),testword.end());
std::sort(testarray.begin(),testarray.end());

bool is_in_array = std::includes(testarray.begin(),testarray.end(),
    testword.begin(),testword.end());
```

This also handles all cases of duplicate letters correctly.
The complexity of this approach should be `O(n * log n)` where `n` is the length of `testarray`. (`sort` is `O(n log n)` and `includes` has linear complexity.